# Error :Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin

I share my code to connect to SQLSERVER :

```
public class Context:DbContext
{
    private readonly IDbConn dbConn;
    public Context()
    {
        dbConn = new DbConn();
    }

    public DbSet<table1> t1{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<table2> t2{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(dbConn.Connection);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<table1>().HasKey(x => new { x.column1, x.column2});

        modelBuilder.Entity<table2>().HasKey(x => new { x.column1, x.column2});
    }
}
```

- 

```
public class DbConn : IDbConn
{
    private SqlConnection sqlConnection;

    public SqlConnection Connection
    {
        
        get
        {
            return new SqlConnection(@"SERVER=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx; Password=xxxxxx");
        }
    }
}
```

- 

```
public class Test
{
    public static table1 GetFirst()
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var cb = context.t1.FirstOrDefault();    //The error occurs here
            return cb;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm a beginner in XAMARIN project.
I try to connect to SQLSERVER and try to get some data from database, but when I execute a LINQ request, I get an error. I already tried to change the connectionStrings but still have the same error.
Can someone help me to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try following the instructions in the error message? To start the SQL Server Browser?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and yes i checked the services, it's activated.

Comment: It's rather problem with environment... you have different network on client and server, or firewall, or server accept connections only from localhost ...

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but we have a lot of software connected to the database, everything is working properly for other project. In this XAMARIN project i'm using EF Core SQLServer to connect, but it's not working, maybe there is an error on my code? I forgot maybe something ?

Comment: you should NOT do this.  Connecting directly from a mobile client to a SQL server is a horrible security risk and should be avoided.  Using a webservice layer between your client and the DB is the generally accepted best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your sql server is on a fixed port you can just say what port it is using. Normally not needed for standard ports

```
return new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxxxxx,portnumberhere;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx; Password=xxxxxx");
```

if you are using dynamic ports you normally need to give the instance name.

```
return new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxxxxx\myinstance;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx; Password=xxxxxx");
```

check no firewalls are blocking traffic between you and the server you are using and as the message says you may in some cases need to ensure the browser service on the database server is running, particularly if using dynamic ports.

[image: browser service]

Edit:

I think the issue could be where you use

```
return new SqlConnection(@"SERVER=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx; Password=xxxxxx");
```

instead off

```
return new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx; Password=xxxxxx");
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, sorry I forgot to said it in my post, i'm using dynamic ports, and my connectionString contains an instance like you said (xxxxxx\myinstance).

Comment: All services are already activated, no problem for the firewalls

Comment: Can you connect using anything eg Sql Management studio on that machine?

Comment: Actually it could be it should be return

 new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxxxxx\myinstance;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx; Password=xxxxxx"); rather than server edited my original answer to correct that

Comment: Yes I can connect to the server with SqlManagement

Comment: Maybe there is an error on my code ? I maybe forgot something ?

Comment: Yes i think there is you use server=. It should actually be "Data Source=

Comment: Edited original answer

Comment: It's propably not an error of connectionStrings, because I use the same connectionStrings in my all project, and it's working